# PHP - Get a count of Multi-dimensional arrays within an associative array and indexed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a multi-dimensional array which consists of indexed arrays within an associative array.

How can I get a separate count of `indexed arrays` as well as `associative arrays` which host the indexed array.

Using `sizeof($jArray, 1)` results into 197 in my case which is the total of key-value pairs + indexed arrays + associative array (49*3 + 49 + 1).

`Count($jArray)` results into `1`, which I'm guessing is the associative array.

JSON structure:

```
Name
│
│───[0] 
│    └── Key -> Value
│    └── Key -> Value
│    └── Key -> Value
└───[1] 
│    └── Key -> Value
│    └── Key -> Value
│    └── Key -> Value
│...
│
└───[n]
     └── Key -> Value
     └── Key -> Value
     └── Key -> Value
```

The count(s) that I'm looking for here are

```
49 - (indexed arrays within associative array 'Name')
147 - (total key-value pairs within indexed array)
3 - (key-value pairs within an indexed array)
```

Comment: That count looks funny... any chance that's actually an object and not an array?

Comment: Any chance you can include a part of the array as Json or var_export for us to try on?

Comment: @Andreas, Sorry I was unable to include the json. I've managed to get the count now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code reproduce your multidimensional array for test purpose:

```
 $arrs=array_fill_keys(['name'],array_fill(0,49,['key1'=>1,'key2'=>2,'key3'=>2,]));
```

According to this:

> 49 - (indexed arrays within associative array 'Name')
>
> 147 - (total key-value pairs within indexed array)
>
> 3 - (key-value pairs within an indexed array)

and specifically the third line,all your counts are simplified to some simple operations that you can achieve this way:

```
$InArWiAsArNa=count($arrs['name']);
$KV_wi_IA=count(current($arrs['name']));
$total_KV_pairs_wi_IA=$InArWiAsArNa*$KV_wi_IA;

var_dump($InArWiAsArNa,$total_KV_pairs_wi_IA,$KV_wi_IA);
```

output:

```
int(49)
int(147)
int(3)
```

however if you remove the third condition, for example if the key-value pairs within an indexed array number is variable, this mean you don't need it anymore so you should loop through the array to get the two first answers:

```
$InArWiAsArNa=0;
$total_KV_pairs_wi_IA=0;
foreach($arrs['name'] as $key=>$val){
    $InArWiAsArNa ++;
    $total_KV_pairs_wi_IA+=count($val);  
}

var_dump($InArWiAsArNa,$total_KV_pairs_wi_IA);
```

output:

```
 int(49)
 int(147)
```

Comment: Very detailed and informative. Thank you. That worked :)

Answer (score 1):

you can always use count() to do that, for example if you have the following array:

```
 $arrs = [
'name1' => [
    [
        'key1'=>1,
        'key2'=>2,
    ],
    [
        'key3'=>3,
    ],
    [
        'key4'=>4,
        'key5'=>5,
        'key6'=>6,
    ],
],
'name2' => [
    [
        'key7'=>7,
    ],
],
```

];

$arrs is a multidimensional array of order 3, to get the number of elements in level 0 which are name1 and name2 (associative arrays),you can just use : `count($arrs);`, this will return 2.
if you want the number of elements of name1 : `count($arrs[name1])`, this will return 3.
if you want the total of elements in name1 and name2,

`$total=0;
foreach($arrs as $arr) $total+=count($arr);`
if you want the total of key-value pairs :

```
foreach($arrs as $arr){
```

`foreach($arr as $ar) $total+=count($ar);
}`